# How to show boolean-based values, in datatable cell content, using lightning design-system-react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, salesforce-lightning

One of the values rendered in my  is a boolean. I'm following the "Advanced: Joined with Page Header" from the [components page](https://react.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/data-tables), and I don't know how to render it correctly and without raising errors in my browser console. Here is my current code:

```
const CustomBooleanActiveCell = ({ children }) => {
 const stringVal = children ? "Active" : "Inactive";
 return <DataTableCell title={stringVal}>{stringVal}</DataTableCell>;
};
CustomBooleanActiveCell.displayName = DataTableCell.displayName;
//...
<DataTableColumn label="Active" property="active">
      <CustomBooleanActiveCell />
</DataTableColumn>
```

This way I'm able to render "active" and "inactive" in my table, but it raises a ton of errors in chrome's console:

[image: first error]
[image: second error]

Vscode also complains about both my `CustomBooleanActiveCell` and the example's `CustomDataTableCell`, saying `Property 'children' is missing in type '{}' but required in type '{ [x: string]: any; children: any; }'`.

How can I change the content of a cell in this datatable? I can map the data before feeding the datatable, but I prefer to edit it in the datatable. Also can I choose to show this data in the datatable without writing `CustomDataTableCell`s?

edit: I am running `design-system-react v0.10.32`, `react v17.0.2`, `next v10.2.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a hook for initialize your stringVal before the request..

```
const [stringVal, setStringVal] = useState("Inactive");
useEffect(() => {
  setStringVal("your result here");
}, [children]);
```